# Why does the magnitude of the cross-product of a and b give the area of a parallelogram spanned by a and b?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, cross-product, surface-integrals

I tried looking it up but many websites just state it without proof and without intuition.  I'm hoping to learn it a little bit better so that I don't forget how to compute the Jacobian when working with surface integrals where the divergence theorem is not applicable.

If you have a good online reference instead, please feel free to provide it :-)

Thanks,

Comment: If you define the cross product by $a \cdot (b \times c) = \det(a,b,c)$ (the best definition of the cross product, IMO), and knowing that determinants represent the volumes of parallelotopes, this just comes down to [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Choose coordinates so that the two vectors $\vec a, \vec b$ are in the $xy$-plane, with $\vec a$ along the $x$-axis. (Note that as long as you've decided on a unit *length*, exactly which direction you choose for the coordinate axes doesn't change anything. The vectors and their cross product live in a coordinate-free space, just floating around. We're just imposing coordinates to make concrete calculations simpler.) That means we can set $\vec a = (a_1, 0, 0)$ and $\vec b = (b_1, b_2, 0)$. This gives
$$
\vec{a}\times \vec b = (0, 0, a_1b_2)
$$
and the length of this vector is $\sqrt{(a_1b_2)^2} = |a_1b_2|$, obviously. But the parallelogram has base $|a_1|$ and height $|b_2|$, which means that the area of the parallelogram is given by the exact same expression.

Comment: Hi @Arthur - very cool and simple answer.  Just a quick follow-up question - you meant for the vector b to have coordinates **(0,$b_2$,0)**, right?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames No, in that case it would be established that $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are perpendicular, which is not assumed. We know that $a_2=0$ since that's how we chose the coordinate system, but for $\vec b$ we can only tell that it lies in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: Hi @Arthur  hmm...isn't the base |a| = |$a_1$|, but then the height is |b| = $\sqrt{b_1^2 + b_2^2}$?  Then the product |a||b| doesn't equal $|a_1b_1|$, which is the magnitude of the cross-product.  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames No, the height of a parallelogram is perpendicular to the base, so $\vec b$ isn't the height.

Comment: Ok, got it now - thanks so much for your help and patience @arthur.  Have a great night.

Comment: If $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ not perpendicular? They are not base and height?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter No, they aren't necessarily perpendicular. A parallelogram isn't required to have perpendicular sides. $\vec a$ is the base, though.

Comment: Ok. But on google image area of parallelogram is height×base and always height is perpendicular to the base...??

Comment: @Lifeforbetter True, and $\vec a$ is the base, but $\vec b$ is not the height.

Answer (score 7):

It is probably because the answer is simple in terms of classical 2D geometry.

$||\vec u\times \vec v||=||\vec u||.||\vec v||.\sin(\vec u,\vec v)$

But the area of the parallelogram defined by $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ is the base multiplied by the height. If you take $\vec u$ as the base, the height is $h=||\vec v||.\sin(\vec u,\vec v)$, hence the result...

Comment: Hi @Martigan, is your equation a *definition* ... or can it be derived from basic geometry?  If it is a derivation, do you mind just explaining a bit more about where it comes from?  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

$|A×B|=|A| ×|B|\sin \theta $ where $\theta$ is the angle between A and B
Using simple trigonometry then we let the height of the parallelogram be a letter say X

The area of a parallelogram is given by base × height

$\sin\theta=X/|A|$ 
Which means that  $X= |A| \sin\theta $

Therefore the area will be given by the base $|B| ×  |A| \sin\theta $
That is essentially the magnitude of the cross product of A and B

Comment: @JMP Despite there's an answer which is very similar to this. I think this one made me understood better. The more you think of it is rather trivial. Unless you forget that the area of a paralellogram is the base times the height just as a rectangle.

Comment: How is $\theta$ defined?  Should this be |A x B| = |A| |B| |sin(theta)|?

Answer (score 0):

Define $A \times_1 B, A \times_2 B$ as the vectors perpendicular to $A, B$, with orientation picked by the right hand rule, and with magnitude $|A||B|sin \theta$, respectively the absolute value of
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 
\bf{i} & \bf{j} & \bf{k} \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3
\end{vmatrix} 
$$
A simple geometric proof shows $A \times_1 B$ is linearly dependent in $A, B$. And determinant properties show that $A \times_2 B$ is linearly dependent in $A, B$ also. It remains to observe that $\times_1, \times_2$ coincide on basis vectors $\bf{i}, \bf{j}, \bf{k}$, which means, as expected, that $\times_1 = \times_2$.